# onCreate method called again on HOME button pressed in androidTV 12 launcher

Tags: android, react-native, launcher, android-launcher, android-12

I have a launcher application written in react native - it is being launched when pressing home button. On Android 10 everything works fine, but on Android 12 if the app is already running and i press home button again the app is reinitialised. I expect nothing to happen if its running already.

What I already tried/checked:

1. setting launchMode in AndroidManifest (android:launchMode="singleTop" / singleTask)
2. `onCreate` method of MainActivity is called again, `isTaskRoot()` is always true.
3. logging intent in `onNewIntent` of Main activity :

`{ act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000100 cmp=my.package/tv.package.MainActivity (has extras) }`

Is there any way to prevent the app from re-launching when pressing home button? Anything else I can check?

I noticed, that if i kill the app from android settings and launch it by pressing home button, next home button press will do nothing (as expected). But when the app is launched from android settings, pressing home button will relaunch it.

Thank you for any suggestions!